# Version problems and errors in Java, Lucene , BM25 based search engine

Tags: java, apache, lucene, search-engine

I am having serious version issues in Java, Lucene based search engine. I have modified and merged the code from too many sources on the internet (relied on this one the most http://ipl.cs.aueb.gr/stougiannis/bm25_2.html) which is most likely why the code is not working. Also, I have referenced lucene-analyzers-4.5.1.jar, lucence-core-4.5.1.jar,lucene-demo-4.5.1.jar, lucene-queryparser-4.5.1.jar,lucene-BM25-1.0.jar,lucene core of 2.9,2.4 (as mentioned in the instructions) and 3.0.3.

this is one of the simple working codes without BM25  which i modified to include BM25 scoring and to add documents to index:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.*;
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;
import org.apache.lucene.search.*;
import org.apache.lucene.store.*;
import org.apache.lucene.util.*;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.*;
import org.ninit.models.bm25.*;//5

import java.io.IOException;

public class lucene12   {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    // 0. Specify the analyzer for tokenizing text.
    //    The same analyzer should be used for indexing and searching
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);

    // 1. create the index
    Directory index = new RAMDirectory();

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);

    IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
    addDoc(w, "Lucene in Action", "193398817");
    addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
    addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
    addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
    w.close();

    // 2. query
    String querystr = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "lucene";

    // the "title" arg specifies the default field to use
    // when no field is explicitly specified in the query.
    Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);

    // 3. search
    int hitsPerPage = 10;
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

    // 4. display results
    System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
    for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
      int docId = hits[i].doc;
      Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
      System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("isbn") + "\t" + d.get("title"));
    }

    // reader can only be closed when there
    // is no need to access the documents any more.
    reader.close();
  }

  private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));

    // use a string field for isbn because we don't want it tokenized
    doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
    w.addDocument(doc);
  }
}
```

---

And this is my code (I am new to java):

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
//import org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
//import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
//import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
//import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;
import org.apache.lucene.search.*;
import org.ninit.models.bm25.*;//5

public class Lucene11  {





public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {


         IndexReader reader= null; 
         Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT); **<<Error here**
         Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
         IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_29, analyzer);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, analyzer);
        addDoc(w, "Lucene in Action", "193398817");
        addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
        addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
        addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
        w.close();


        BM25BooleanQuery query = null;

        try {
            query = new BM25BooleanQuery( "lucene" ,"title",analyzer);
        } catch (org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int hitsPerPage = 10;

       try {
          reader=IndexReader.open(index);
       }
       catch (CorruptIndexException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
       catch(IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
       String field="title";
       Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    BM25Parameters.setAverageLength("title",getAvgLength(reader,"title"));
    BM25Parameters.setB(0.75f);
    BM25Parameters.setK1(2f);

    TopDocs top=searcher.search(query, hitsPerPage);
       ScoreDoc[] docs = top.scoreDocs;
       for (int i= 0;i<10; i++){
          System.out.println("the document with id= " + docs[i].doc + " has score ="+docs[i].score);
       } 

    reader.close();
  }


  public static float getAvgLength(IndexReader reader,String field) throws IOException{
     long sum=0;
     for (int i = 0; i < reader.numDocs(); i++){
       TermFreqVector tfv=
                reader.getTermFreqVector(i, field);
        if(tfv!= null) {
           int[] tfs=tfv.getTermFrequencies();
           for(int j= 0;j < tfv.size(); j++){
              sum=sum+tfs[j];
           }
        }
     } 
     float avg=(float)sum/reader.numDocs(); 
     //System.out.println("average length = " + avg);
     return avg;
  }//end of method


  private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new  TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));

    // use a string field for isbn because we don't want it tokenized
    doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
    w.addDocument(doc);
  }
}
```

the error on " Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);" line says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_31
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharacterUtils.getInstance(CharacterUtils.java:46)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArrayMap.<init>(CharArrayMap.java:85)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArrayMap$EmptyCharArrayMap.<init>(CharArrayMap.java:662)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArrayMap.<clinit>(CharArrayMap.java:55)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet.<clinit>(CharArraySet.java:59)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopAnalyzer.<clinit>(StopAnalyzer.java:58)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.<clinit>(StandardAnalyzer.java:64)
at Lucene11.main(Lucene11.java:55)
```

---

Score function modified:

```
package org.ninit.models.bm25;


import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.TermDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Explanation;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Scorer;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Similarity;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;

public class BM25TermScorer extends Scorer {

    private TermQuery term;
    private IndexReader reader;
    private TermDocs termDocs;
    private float idf;
    private float av_length;
    private byte[] norm;
    private float b;
    private float k1;

    public BM25TermScorer(IndexReader reader, TermQuery term, Similarity similarity)
            throws IOException {
        super(similarity);
        this.reader = reader;
        this.term = term;
        this.idf = this.getSimilarity().idf(reader.docFreq(term.getTerm()), reader.numDocs());
        this.norm = this.reader.norms(this.term.getTerm().field());
        this.av_length = BM25Parameters.getAverageLength(this.term.getTerm().field());
        this.b = BM25Parameters.getB();
        this.k1 = BM25Parameters.getK1();
        this.termDocs = this.reader.termDocs(this.term.getTerm());

    }


    @Override
    public int doc() {
        return this.termDocs.doc();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.apache.lucene.search.Scorer#explain(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Explanation explain(int doc) throws IOException {
        // Init termDocs
        if (this.termDocs != null)
            this.termDocs.close();
        this.termDocs = this.reader.termDocs(this.term.getTerm());
        // skipTo doc

        //
        if (!this.skipTo(doc))
            return null;
        float length = 0f;
        byte[] norm = this.reader.norms(this.term.getTerm().field());

        float av_length = BM25Parameters.getAverageLength(this.term.getTerm().field());
        length = 1 / ((Similarity.decodeNorm(norm[this.doc()])) * (Similarity.decodeNorm(norm[this
                .doc()])));

        float tf = this.termDocs.freq();

        float result = BM25Parameters.getB() * (length / av_length);
        result = result + 1 - BM25Parameters.getB();
        result = tf / result;
        // FREQ SATURATION
        result = result / (result + BM25Parameters.getK1());

        Explanation idfE = new Explanation(this.idf, " idf (docFreq:"
                + this.reader.docFreq(this.term.getTerm()) + ",numDocs:" + this.reader.numDocs()
                + ")");
        Explanation bE = new Explanation(result, "B:" + BM25Parameters.getB() + ",Length:" + length
                + ",AvgLength:" + av_length + ",Freq:" + tf + ",K1:" + BM25Parameters.getK1());

        Explanation resultE = new Explanation(this.idf * result, "BM25("
                + this.term.getTerm().field() + ":" + this.term.getTerm().text());
        resultE.addDetail(idfE);
        resultE.addDetail(bE);

        return resultE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws IOException {

        boolean result = this.termDocs.next();
        if (!result)
            this.termDocs.close();
        return result;

    }

    public float score()throws IOException{
        //IDF refers to the inverse document frequency (idf(qi,d)) and
        //TF25 refers to the second factor in the definition of the BM25 scoring function
        float TF25;
        float num25;
        float den25;
        float length;
        float norm = Similarity.decodeNorm(this.norm[this.doc()]);
        length = 1 / (norm * norm);
        den25= this.b*(length / this.av_length);
        den25= 1-this.b+den25;
        den25= this.k1*den25;
        den25= this.termDocs.freq()+den25;
        num25= this.k1+1;
        num25= num25*this.termDocs.freq();
        TF25= num25/den25;
        return TF25*this.idf;

        }//end of score

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.apache.lucene.search.Scorer#skipTo(int)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean skipTo(int target) throws IOException {
        while (this.next() && this.doc() < target) {
        }

        return this.doc() == target;
    }

    public int freq() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int advance(int arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public long cost() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int docID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int nextDoc() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't mix and match lucene versions, and you certainly can't simultaneously use multiple versions of Lucene core.  You say you currently have, in your classpath, Lucene core 2.4, 2.9, 3.0.3, and 4.5.1.  That's really not going to work.  It looks like you want to use Lucene version 4.5.1, so get rid of the other three lucene core jars.  You'll likely need to modify the code you've copied that uses older versions in order to make them compatible with 4.X (the one revealed in the error:  there is no more `Version.LUCENE_CURRENT`, you must specify a particular version).  You can find resources on what changed from 3.6 - 4.0 and how to migrate in the [migration guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html).

As far as the BM25 scoring implementation, there is now (as of 4.0) a [`BM25Similarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html) implementation in lucene core.